# Copy every two cells and transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to transpose every next two cells and paste them in next right cells.

I have a table as shown in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I want to copy range `"B2:B3"` and transpose this to `"C2"` and then loop until there is some data in column B. (so select and copy next `"B4:B5"` and transpose this to `"B4"`).

I cannot get this to transpose in the right place and then loop.

I have something like this (I did not add loop yet to this macro):

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long
    a = ActiveCell.Column
    b = ActiveCell.Row

    Range("B2").Select
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(b + 1, a)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code with which you have tried to transpose the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a VBA solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim pasteRng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Set pasteRng = .Range("C1:D2")
        With .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
            For i = 1 To .Rows.count Step 2
                pasteRng.Offset(i).Value = Application.Transpose(.Cells(i, 1).Resize(2))
            Next i
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

No VBA is needed.  In **C2** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/2,0)*2)
```

and copy down and in **D2** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/2,0)*2+1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

and if you need this as part of some VBA effort:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    For i = 2 To 10 Step 2
        Set r1 = Range("B" & i & ":B" & (i + 1))
        Set r2 = Range("C" & i)

        r1.Copy

        r2.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        r2.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate Formula solution and can be applied to variety of situations.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will help resolve me problem in another macro :)